# javascript remove html tags but not content within them and not <a > tags with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

how to remove all tags in a string but not `<a>`? and not the text inside them?

For example: `<em>Bold</em><a>Go here</a>` should be: `Bold<a>Go here</a>`

Comment: Do you want to manipulate a string, or the DOM? Why do you tag regex? Depending on the first question, you may not need them.

Comment: You [shouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1169519) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all strings that look like `<...>` other than `<a>` or `</a>` with

```
<(?!\/?a>)[^>]*>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA8kE1/2)

Do not forget to add a `/i` case  insensitive modifier to also avoid matching `<A>`. If you do not plan to keep closing `</a>`, you can use [`<(?!a>)[^>]*>`](https://regex101.com/r/bA8kE1/1).

Comment: I added optional `\/?` - I guess you wanted to also keep the closing tag, right? I also added the note with my previous regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
  allowed = (((allowed || '') + '')
    .toLowerCase()
    .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
    .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
    commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
  return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '')
    .replace(tags, function($0, $1) {
      return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}

var html = 'some html code';
html = strip_tags(html, '<a>');
```

source: http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/